# How to get specific strings from a text file and assign it to a variable using FileReader/bufferedReader in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, readline

Let's say I have a text file that has something like

```
 bob=345 non=4567
 4
 3      90
 5      567
 56     777

 1
 785    852
 675    236

 5
 6      466
 345    777
```

The numbers on there are arbitrary. I want to be able to assign each number to a variable. So I have a variable for 345, 3456,4,5,90. I was thinking make a search so it reads each character until it reaches a new line, in that new line the when it reads until it reaches a "space" and assign it to a variable and keeps doing that until it reaches an empty line. Then w/e search/loop I made above will repeat until end of file.

Right now I can't even get the first line to work. I have tried two ways so far.

First way is I think could work if I could figure out how to get the index of the end of line.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
   while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

          int variable=line.indexOf("non=")+4;

          int variable2=line.indexOf("");//line.lastIndexOf('\n',variable); 

          variable3=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(variable, variable2));}
```

second way is using splitting the space, but this didn't work b/c it looks for space until end of file not end of line

```
            if(line.contains("non=")){
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                String x = parts[0];
                String y = parts[0];
            }
```

Comment: How could `split()` work on the whole file when you actually call it on a single `line`? It should work just fine.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I exited eclipse and tried to run it again and now it works. Thanks